# Is it possible to create a Array of Elements in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a array of checkboxes so it can be easy to access them through a for loop. Something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i<10, i++)
{
    checkbox[i].visibility(view.GONE);
}
```

But I am not sure if there is a way to create a array like this

Comment: Is it possible? Aboslutely. However, I recommend that you read about RecyclerView. This is the recommended way to display a list of UI elements to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create `array` of `CheckBox` in java like this,

```
CheckBox[] arrayOfCheckBox = new CheckBox[10];
```

But I would suggest use `ArrayList` instead `Array` so it will be easier for you to add *checkboxes* in *ArrayList*

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> arrayListCheckBox = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
arrayListCheckBox.add(checkbox);
```